# Bug ou status-by-design?: barra lateral fica sobre a barra inferior

Tags: bug, layout

*Bug* ou *status-by-design*?: barra lateral fica sobre a barra inferior (na página de criação de uma nova pergunta):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu diria que é bug.

Comment: Também acho que é bug, aqui está igual.

Comment: @bigown ainda noto o bug http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5644/3635

Answer (score 2):

Bom, quando você vai fazer uma nova pergunta e seleciona a opção de **Responder sua própria pergunta – compartilhe seu conhecimento, estilo Q&A**, isso ainda ocorre, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Está marcado como [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto), mas o problema ainda existe:

Se fizer uma pergunta como visitante (não autenticado):

[image: Problema quando não autenticado]

Se fizer uma pergunta de maneira autenticada:

[image: Problema quando autenticado]

Comment: Não está mais :P